# How do I horizontally center <li>'s?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I'm trying to center a few `<li>` in `<ul>`. Here's the mark up;

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/250x200" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/250x200" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/250x200" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/250x200" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've got a bit of css to style the images, so at the moment it looks like this;

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to get the `<li>`'s to stay in the center and still fill the space evenly.
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the width of the `ul` is variable, I think the best way is the following:

```
ul.thumbnails  {
    text-align: center;
}

ul.thumbnails li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```